# Create one of two possible store procedures in one script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, proc

I want to do a check (if statement) and then create one of two  possible procedures.

Right now I am trying to use a `IF EXISTS` statement inside a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

IF EXISTS (select * from table)
BEGIN
DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM User
```

...do something with #TempTable etc..

```
DROP #TempTable
END

ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM User
```

...do something else with #TempTable etc

```
DROP #TempTable
END
```

I get the following 2 errors

```
There is already an object named 'TempTable' in the database.

The variable name '@region' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You need use two different temp table and before SELECT * INTO statements DROP them

2.Variable need once declared in the body procedure. In your case before IF EXISTS

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

DECLARE @region NVARCHAR(100)

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.test6)
BEGIN
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#TempTable
  SELECT *
  INTO #TempTable
  FROM dbo.test6
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempTable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#TempTable2
  SELECT *
  INTO #TempTable2
  FROM dbo.test6
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Either a) Create the temp table first in the stored procedure, then use `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT ...` to populate it, or b) Use a different name for the temp table in the two branches.

The T-SQL parser is a remarkably simple beast, and *control flow* doesn't affect its interpretation of which objects exist or not - so if you declare a temp table in one branch of an `IF`, you can't declare it separately in the other branch - it "exists" whether the control flow enters the `IF` branch or not.

A Similar argument applies for variables.

Obviously, option `a` only works if the temp table structures are identical.

---

Simple example of how control flow is ignored:

```
if 1=2
begin
    declare @a int
end

set @a = 5

print @a
```

prints `5`. Just:

```
set @a = 5

print @a
```

produces the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@a".`, which demonstrates that the declaration (inside the un-followed branch of `if`) still took effect.